# Antialiasing not working in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, antialiasing

I re-implemented **QGraphicsView** to have the scene zoomed with a mouse wheel event. The scene contains several **QGraphicsPixmapItem**. The wheel event calls **QGraphicsView::scale(qreal sx, qreal sy)**

Everything works perfectly but the rendering. As I zoom out (the scene gets smaller), aliasing appears. I tried setting the render hints as following in the re-implemented **QGraphicsView** constructor:

```
ImageViewer::ImageViewer(QWidget * parent) :
  QGraphicsView(parent)
{
   setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
}
```

I still see these artifacts. How can I get rid of this ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what's going on? Are you setting any caching strategy on the items?

Comment: Thank you @peppe ! I'm not setting anything about caching, so I guess it's default. Here's an example of what it looks like [before](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-e2pH06jhy94/Ue09l8A1SWI/AAAAAAAAY08/YGa-wj9ollY/w958-h599-no/Fullscreen+capture+7222013+100003+AM.jpg) (1:1 pixel ratio) and [after](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-PZJVX0jl6yw/Ue09mo_Iu2I/AAAAAAAAY1E/nMf28uA9MlE/w958-h599-no/Fullscreen+capture+7222013+100007+AM.jpg) (less than 1:1 pixel ratio) zooming out. You'll see some aliasing in the concentric circles.

Answer (score 10):

Please see my comments for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652590/smooth-text-animation-marquee-text-effect-using-qt/1662221#1662221).

Basically you have to call `setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation)` on the `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s you want anti-aliasing to apply to.

Calling `setRenderHints` on the view did not work for me, either.

Comment: So there's no way to have an antialiased background? Edit: Nm was an error in my code.

Comment: Using `SmoothTransformation` does some antialiasing when using `fitInView`, but it's basically next to nothing. I now scale the pixmap manually and set `Qt.SmoothTransformation`. This unfortunately wastes lots of time, but the result is much better.

Comment: I get an error saying "no member named 'setTransformationMode' in 'QGraphicsItem'".

Comment: @DonaldDuck It is only for `QGraphicsPixmapItem`.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

The render hints are only applied if it is set bevor the painter is used. Here a snipped:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *
drawGraphicsPixmapItem(const QRectF &rect)
{
    auto pixmap = new QPixmap(rect.size().toSize());
    pixmap->fill("lightGrey");

    auto painter = new QPainter(pixmap);
    // set render hints bevor drawing with painter
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    QPen pen;
    pen.setColor("black");
    pen.setWidth(3);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    QRectF rectT = rect;
    rectT.adjust(pen.widthF()/2,pen.widthF()/2,-pen.widthF()/2,-pen.widthF()/2);

    QPainterPath circlePath;
    circlePath.addEllipse(rectT);
    circlePath.closeSubpath();
    painter->fillPath(circlePath,QBrush("green"));
    painter->drawPath(circlePath);
    auto pixmapItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(*pixmap);
    pixmapItem->setCacheMode(
             QGraphicsItem::CacheMode::DeviceCoordinateCache,
             pixmap->size() );
    return pixmapItem;
}
```