# Smooth Pixmap Transformation in QGraphicsView Does Not Work

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, antialiasing

note: [Antialiasing not working in QGraphicsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734290/antialiasing-not-working-in-qgraphicsview) does not work for me.

I am trying to enable anti-aliasing and/or smooth pixmap transformations to a QGraphicsView. The following is the entire program. It successfully displays the image at 20% scale, but without any smoothing.

Everywhere I've looked, it seems like setting the transformation mode of the QGraphicsPixmapItem and the render hints of the QGraphicsView should be enough, but neither works in my case.

*GraphicsView.pro*

```
QT += core gui widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPixmap>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item;
    QPixmap pixmap;

    pixmap.load("../textures/image.jpg");
    item.setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    item.setPixmap(pixmap);
    scene.addItem(&item);
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
    view.scale(0.2, 0.2);
    window.setCentralWidget(&view);
    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is your question "Why isn't the image smoothing?"  Is it "Why is it at 20% scale?"

Comment: It is "Why isn't the image smoothing?"

Comment: It does work, though it does very very little. Compare two screenshots, one with fast and one with smooth transformation. I solved this by creating a new pixmap scaled to the view size with `Qt.SmoothTransformation`.