# Scaled and transform Qgraphicspixmapitem

Tags: c++, qt, transformation, image-quality, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a problem while scaling and transforming `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. I have created graphics editor in which I am using `QGraphicsItem` of initial size 100,100 and after that I am resizing and rotating it by `setTransform()` method.

After that I am storing this transform and using these for my another application called player in which I am using those transform and showing images and videos on it, I am using `QgraphicsPixmapItem` to show images now if I set scaled and `setTransform` methods to image its clarity gets spoiled.

Is it possible to keep clarity as it is even if I scaled and transform it.The image I am using is of 2560x1440 pixels. 
Any help will be appreciated.

The code is :

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pixitem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
pixitem->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
pixitem->setPos(50,50);
QTransform trans;
trans.setMatrix(4.20399,2.9286,0,-3.86601,0.761397,0,33.1015,-134.5,1);
pixitem->setPixmap(QPixmap("abc.jpg").scaled(100,100));
pixitem->setTransform(trans);
pixitem->setShapeMode(QGraphicsPixmapItem::MaskShape);
scene->addItem(pixitem);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTransformationMode` function to set the pixmap item's transformation mode. The default value is  `Qt::FastTransformation`. You should set the transform mode to `Qt::SmoothTransformation` to enable bilinear filtering which results in a better quality when scaled :

```
pixitem->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Netaj. Image is more clear than before but not as it is with its original pixels.Is there any way to prevent original clarity.

Comment: When scaling, quality reduction is inevitable. Techniques like smooth transformation just makes it better and nothing more could be done.

Comment: Thanks for responding :)

Comment: Using SVG image with QGraphicsSvgItem could help preserve the quality

Comment: @Arun , QGraphicsSvgItem seems only handle svg files? How about the other files?